# Page works good but is not scrollable

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on a lottery app and have coded the UI for it. 
The problem is that my page is not scrollable right now.

It may be because of the gradient background I've added.

I've searched for several solutions but none of them worked:

[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20038673/my-html-page-is-not-scrolling-in-browsers/20038715)
[StacjOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575251/why-is-my-page-not-scrollable)

Here is a link to the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/leocete/pen/eXbRmo)

My index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Lottery app</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

    <main class="container">
        <section class="lottery-page">
            <h1 class="main-header">WELCOME TO THE LOTTERY!</h1>
            <h2 class="action-header">Please, enter your winnings numbers here (from 0 to 52):</h2>

            <div class="user-input">
                <div class="number-wrapper">
                    <label for="user-number_1">1st number</label>
                    <input id="user-number_1" class="lottery-number" type="number" maxlength="2">
                    <span class="focus-border">
                            <i></i>
                          </span>
                </div>

                <div class="number-wrapper">
                    <label for="user-number_1">2nd number</label>
                    <input id="user-number_2" class="lottery-number" type="number" maxlength="2">
                    <span class="focus-border">
                            <i></i>
                          </span>
                </div>

                <div class="number-wrapper">
                    <label for="user-number_1">3rd number</label>
                    <input id="user-number_3" class="lottery-number" type="number" maxlength="2">
                    <span class="focus-border">
                            <i></i>
                          </span>
                </div>

                <div class="number-wrapper">
                    <label for="user-number_1">4th number</label>
                    <input id="user-number_4" class="lottery-number" type="number" maxlength="2">
                    <span class="focus-border">
                            <i></i>
                          </span>
                </div>

                <div class="number-wrapper">
                    <label for="user-number_1">5th number</label>
                    <input id="user-number_5" class="lottery-number" type="number" maxlength="2">
                    <span class="focus-border">
                            <i></i>
                          </span>
                </div>

                <div class="number-wrapper">
                    <label for="user-number_1">6th number</label>
                    <input id="user-number_6" class="lottery-number" type="number" maxlength="2">
                    <span class="focus-border">
                            <i></i>
                          </span>
                </div>

                <div class="number-wrapper">
                    <label for="user-draw">Number of draws</label>
                    <input id="user-draw" class="draw-number" type="number" maxlength="6">
                    <span class="focus-border">
                            <i></i>
                          </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="submit-button">
                <button id="button-send_results" type = "submit">Let's win!</button>
            </div>
            <div class="user-results">

            </div>
        </section>
    </main>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
html, body {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}


.container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: center;
}

.container::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at bottom right, #aef78e, #77BA99,#aef78e);
    background-size: 400% 400%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    animation: ambient 25s ease-in-out infinite;
    z-index: -1; 
}

@keyframes ambient {
    0%{background-position:0% 50%}
    50%{background-position:100% 50%}
    100%{background-position:0% 50%}
}

.lottery-page {
    width: 80%;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-style : inset;
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding: 50px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.main-header {
    padding: 0px, 50px, 50px, 50px;
}

.lottery-number,  .lottery-number_label, .draw-number{
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}

.user-input {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 100px, 0px;
    padding: 100px, 0px;
}
.action-header {
    margin-bottom: 70px;
}

label, input {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  margin: 0; 
}

input[type="number"] {
    font: 15px/24px 'Muli', sans-serif; 
    color: #333; 
    width: 150px; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin: 30px;
}

.number-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

/* Input animation */
.lottery-number {
    border: 3px solid #ccc; 
    padding: 7px 14px 9px; 
    transition: 0.4s;
}
```

Comment: Any reason you're using `position:fixed` on your container and applying your gradient to that instead of the `<body>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is because you've added `position: fixed;` on your container. I would apply your background as a `background-image` element on your `<body>` tag in CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `position:fixed` from `.container` style and remove `.container::before` style and set `background` to .container style. Also remove the `overflow:scroll` from body style.

```css
html, body {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}


.container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: center;
  
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at bottom right, #aef78e, #77BA99,#aef78e);
    background-size: 400% 400%;
    animation: ambient 25s ease-in-out infinite;
}
@keyframes ambient {
    0%{background-position:0% 50%}
    50%{background-position:100% 50%}
    100%{background-position:0% 50%}
}

.lottery-page {
    width: 80%;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-style : inset;
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding: 50px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.main-header {
    padding: 0px, 50px, 50px, 50px;
}

.lottery-number,  .lottery-number_label, .draw-number{
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}

.user-input {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 100px, 0px;
    padding: 100px, 0px;
}
.action-header {
    margin-bottom: 70px;
}

label, input {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  margin: 0; 
}

input[type="number"] {
    font: 15px/24px 'Muli', sans-serif; 
    color: #333; 
    width: 150px; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin: 30px;
}

.number-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

/* Input animation */
.lottery-number {
    border: 3px solid #ccc; 
    padding: 7px 14px 9px; 
    transition: 0.4s;
}
.lottery-number ~ .focus-border:before,
.lottery-number ~ .focus-border:after{content: ""; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 0; height: 2px; background-color: #4caf50; transition: 0.3s;}
.lottery-number ~ .focus-border:after{top: auto; bottom: 0; left: auto; right: 0;}
.lottery-number ~ .focus-border i:before,
.lottery-number ~ .focus-border i:after{content: ""; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 4px; height: 0; background-color: #4caf50; transition: 0.4s;}
.lottery-number ~ .focus-border i:after{left: auto; right: 0; top: auto; bottom: 0;}
.lottery-number:focus ~ .focus-border:before,
.lottery-number:focus ~ .focus-border:after{width: 100%; transition: 0.4s;}
.lottery-number:focus ~ .focus-border i:before,
.lottery-number:focus ~ .focus-border i:after{height: 100%; transition: 0.5s;}

.draw-number {
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    padding: 7px 14px 9px; 
    transition: 0.4s;
}
.draw-number ~ .focus-border:before,
.draw-number~ .focus-border:after{content: ""; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 0; height: 2px; background-color: #4caf50; transition: 0.3s;}
.draw-number ~ .focus-border:after{top: auto; bottom: 0; left: auto; right: 0;}
.draw-number ~ .focus-border i:before,
.draw-number ~ .focus-border i:after{content: ""; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 2px; height: 0; background-color: #4caf50; transition: 0.4s;}
.draw-number ~ .focus-border i:after{left: auto; right: 0; top: auto; bottom: 0;}
.draw-number:focus ~ .focus-border:before,
.draw-number:focus ~ .focus-border:after{width: 100%; transition: 0.3s;}
.draw-number:focus ~ .focus-border i:before,
.draw-number:focus ~ .focus-border i:after{height: 100%; transition: 0.4s;}

/* Button styles */

#button-send_results {
    border: none;
    background: #e0f008;
    color: #000000 !important;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 6px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
}

#button-send_results:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fdfdfd !important;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    background: rgb(11, 56, 33);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 40px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.57);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 40px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.57);
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Lottery app</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    
    <main class="container">
        <section class="lottery-page">
            <h1 class="main-header">WELCOME TO THE LOTTERY!</h1>
            <h2 class="action-header">Please, enter your winnings numbers here (from 0 to 52):</h2>

            <div class="user-input">
                <div class="number-wrapper">
                    <label for="user-number_1">1st number</label>
                    <input id="user-number_1" class="lottery-number" type="number" maxlength="2">
                    <span class="focus-border">
                            <i></i>
                          </span>
                </div>
            
                <div class="number-wrapper">
                    <label for="user-number_1">2nd number</label>
                    <input id="user-number_2" class="lottery-number" type="number" maxlength="2">
                    <span class="focus-border">
                            <i></i>
                          </span>
                </div>

                <div class="number-wrapper">
                    <label for="user-number_1">3rd number</label>
                    <input id="user-number_3" class="lottery-number" type="number" maxlength="2">
                    <span class="focus-border">
                            <i></i>
                          </span>
                </div>

                <div class="number-wrapper">
                    <label for="user-number_1">4th number</label>
                    <input id="user-number_4" class="lottery-number" type="number" maxlength="2">
                    <span class="focus-border">
                            <i></i>
                          </span>
                </div>

                <div class="number-wrapper">
                    <label for="user-number_1">5th number</label>
                    <input id="user-number_5" class="lottery-number" type="number" maxlength="2">
                    <span class="focus-border">
                            <i></i>
                          </span>
                </div>

                <div class="number-wrapper">
                    <label for="user-number_1">6th number</label>
                    <input id="user-number_6" class="lottery-number" type="number" maxlength="2">
                    <span class="focus-border">
                            <i></i>
                          </span>
                </div>

                <div class="number-wrapper">
                    <label for="user-draw">Number of draws</label>
                    <input id="user-draw" class="draw-number" type="number" maxlength="6">
                    <span class="focus-border">
                            <i></i>
                          </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="submit-button">
                <button id="button-send_results" type = "submit">Let's win!</button>
            </div>
            <div class="user-results">

            </div>
        </section>
    </main>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can also test it [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bZORox)

Answer (score 0):

It is your `position: fixed;` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

it's because of `position: fixed;` on line no 11 in CSS.
 just remove it'll work.